# implement sorting in java for file with records

Tags: java, file, sorting, io, bubble-sort

I asked this question earlier and I forgot to clarify what my question was so hopefully I'm actually clear this time.

I basically need help with sorting a bunch of records in a file based on their number using an algorithm like bubble sort.

I have a file with 5 records where each file consists of a number of integer type and name of 32 characters(each record size should be 36 bytes). I have to store the records into a file. **This is what I need help with:**Then sort the records based on the numbers associated with them, using a sorting algorithm like bubble sort. Another requirement is that when the program sorts the records, it shouldn't read all records in memory at once but move them in the file. For example, after the program reads the first two records, it may switch the records (because 72 > 56) and write them in the same position in the file.

We were provided with the classes to read/write and have random access to the file.

These are the records as they were provided:

72      James

56      Mark

87      John

30      Phillip

44      Andrew

I need to sort these names according to their respective numbers. My question is, what would be the best way to implement this sorting?

Here's the code for the writing class:

```
package test;

//write to a file
import java.io.*; 

class FileWriteStreamTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        FileWriteStreamTest f = new FileWriteStreamTest();
        f.writeMyFile();
        }
    void writeMyFile()  {
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String record = null;
        int recCount = 0;
        try {
            File f = new File("mydata.txt");
            if (!f.exists())
                f.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); 
            dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
            //store records into file
            dos.writeBytes(72 + "   James                      \n");
            dos.writeBytes(56 + "   Mark                       \n");
            dos.writeBytes(87 + "   John                       \n");
            dos.writeBytes(30 + "   Phillip                    \n");
            dos.writeBytes(44 + "   Andrew                     \n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Uh oh, got an IOException error!" + e.getMessage()); 
        } finally {
            // if the file opened okay, make sure we close it
            if (dos != null) {
            try { dos.close(); }
            catch (IOException ioe) { }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the reading class:

```
package test;

//read from a file
import java.io.*; 

public class FileReadStreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileReadStreamTest f = new FileReadStreamTest();
        f.readMyFile(); 

    }
    void readMyFile() {
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        String record = null;
        int recCount = 0; 

        try {
            File f = new File("mydata.txt");
            if (!f.exists()) {
            System.out.println(f.getName() + " does not exist");
            return;
        }
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            dis = new DataInputStream(bis); 

            while ( (record=dis.readLine()) != null ) {
                recCount++;
                System.out.println(recCount + ": " + record);
                } 
    }  catch (IOException e)  {
        System.out.println("Uh oh, got an IOException error!" + e.getMessage()); 
    } finally {
        // if the file opened okay, make sure we close it
        if (dis != null) {
            try { dis.close(); }
            catch (IOException ioe) { }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the random access class:

```
package test;

//read or write to any place in the file
import java.io.*; 

class FileRandomAccessTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        FileRandomAccessTest f = new FileRandomAccessTest();
        f.readWriteMyFile();
        } 
    void readWriteMyFile() {
        RandomAccessFile raf = null;
        String s = null;

        try {
            File f = new File("mydata.txt");
            if (!f.exists()) // check if the file exists
                f.createNewFile(); // create a new file
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw"); // open a file for random access with "r", "rw"
            if (raf.length() > 7) {// the size of the file
                raf.seek(7); // move the file pointer
                System.out.println(raf.readLine()); // read a line from the file pointer
                s = raf.readLine();
                System.out.println(s);
                raf.seek(raf.getFilePointer() - s.length()); // get the file pointer
                raf.writeBytes("Test RamdomAccessFile\n"); // write bytes
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Uh oh, got an IOException error!" + e.getMessage()); 
        } finally {
            // if the file opened okay, make sure we close it
            if (raf != null) {
                try { raf.close(); } // close the file
                catch (IOException ioe) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My current bubble sort implementation that needs to be adapted for this problem:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sort {

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] num ) {
        int j;
        boolean flag = true;   // set flag to true to begin first pass
        int temp;   //holding variable

        while ( flag ) {
            flag= false;    //set flag to false awaiting a possible swap
            for( j=0;  j < num.length -1;  j++ ) {
                if ( num[ j ] < num[j+1] )  {
                    temp = num[ j ];                //swap elements
                    num[ j ] = num[ j+1 ];
                    num[ j+1 ] = temp;
                    flag = true;              //shows a swap occurred  
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
        int [] numbers = new int [5];
        int i = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
           numbers[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        bubbleSort(numbers);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

    }
}
```

Comment: The code works, but I'm not sure how to do the implementation for sorting the file. How could I do that part? All I can do is read/write and random access.

Comment: Bubble sort will work like you mentioned.

Comment: @tima So would I have another class to do that implementation?

Comment: You can do it in another class or in one of the existing classes

Comment: @tima Based on my knowledge so far, I understand how to just read a set of numbers from a file, and sort it and output the result. But when I have more characters associated with each number, how could I sort the numbers and display the associated names with each number in order?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are reading a set of numbers. You are using `.readLine()` which should have each line. And you didn't provide your current implementation of any sorting.

Comment: @tima So I've added an implementation of bubble sort I had previously and it only takes numbers and can't really work with strings. How can I adapt it to this case so that when I read each line, I can take the integers, sort them, and sort the lines accordingly?

Comment: To do this correctly, you need file I/O functions that let you specify file offset and size for each record. You also need to decide if you want line terminators on the records, which is just newline for Linux, or carriage return + newline for Windows. The file I/O functions should take file handle / descriptor / ..., index to record, and record buffer as parameters. The sort code would need two record buffers to do the compare and swap if needed.

Comment: @rcgldr sorry can you explain that in a bit more simple terms?

Comment: @zachem69 - you need to created I/O functions that allow you to read and write individual (fixed length) records within a file.

Comment: @rcgldr So I can think of how to read and write records as just strings. But how could I reorder the strings based on the numbers? Would the only way be to read the 1st 2 characters in each string, convert those to integers and sort them with bubble sort? What do you suggest?

Comment: @zachem69 - the  assignment here is to treat the file similar to a matrix, where each record is a row of the matrix. The code needs to read two records at a time into a pair of buffers, compare the record images in the buffers (converting strings to integers if needed), and if they are out of order, then the code writes them back to the file in proper order, similar to  swapping rows in a matrix.